# How much does Fertility boost percentages?

Tags: reus

In Reus, the fertility boosts say that they give a greater chance to get better aspects on a source.

When I use a level 1 Fertility Boost on a patch and then use a level 1 Leaf Aspect, it gives a 100% chance of a Potent Leaf Aspect. However, when I use a level 2 Fertility Boost and a level 2 Leaf Aspect, I do not get 100% chance for a Greater Leaf Aspect. So what is the chance?

- No Fertility Boost

  - Level 1 Aspect: 66% Lesser, 33% Potent
  - Level 2 Aspect: 66% Potent, 33% Greater
  - Level 3 Aspect: 66% Greater, 33% Sublime
- Level 1 Fertility Boost

  - Level 1 Aspect: 100% Potent
  - Level 2 Aspect: Same as no boost?
  - Level 3 Aspect: Same as no boost?
- Level 2 Fertility Boost

  - Level 1 Aspect: 100% Potent
  - Level 2 Aspect: ???
  - Level 3 Aspect: Same as no boost?
- Level 3 Fertility Boost

  - Level 1 Aspect: 100% Potent
  - Level 2 Aspect: Same as Level 2 Fertility Boost?
  - Level 3 Aspect: ???

Side note: I am aware that fertility boosts make the aspects better. An aspect given on a patch with a fertility boost will have the ability to give better results based on the Natura on the patch.